# Терминал mac os: поменять фон рабочего стола

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

Какая команда в терминале на mac os меняет фон рабочего стола? 
(Хочу забиндить на сочетании клавиш)

Answer (score 0):

С установленным Homebrew:

```
brew install m-cli 
m wallpaper ./wallpapers/картинка.jpg
```